# Vibrate to Sound iphone

Tags: iphone, audio, vibration

I am working on the video application. and My phone is on vibration or silent and I play the video then sound of video does not play. But I want to play sound even phone is on silent or vibration. So please let me know is it possible? If yes then How? please provide me sample source code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IOS doesnt give your app that kind of control. 
When the user turned ios to silent all apps are silent.